# Using GPUImageFilterLookup on live video

Tags: ios, swift, gpuimage, gpuimagestillcamera

I am able to use the GPUImageLookupFilter on still images with no problem but I am not able to apply the lookup filter to live video. Is it possible? If so how?

This is what I have for still images:

```
var filteredImage:UIImage!
func lookupFilter() {
    let stillImageSource = GPUImagePicture(image: UIImage(named: "lookup"))
    let filterApplied = GPUImagePicture(image: UIImage(named: "lookupF"))
    let lookup = GPUImageLookupFilter()
    stillImageSource.addTarget(lookup)
    filterApplied.addTarget(lookup)
    lookup.useNextFrameForImageCapture()
    stillImageSource.processImage()
    filterApplied.processImage()
    lookup.imageFromCurrentFramebuffer()
    filteredImage = lookup.imageFromCurrentFramebuffer()
}
```

AKA is it possible to have the "stillImageSource" be a live video stream from the camera?

Comment: Did you ever solve this? I'm having the same issue.

Comment: @DanH No I ended up taking the photo unfiltered and then applying the lookup filter to the still image.